# How to find theoretically the decay width of a particle-decay process?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, leptons

The problem is devided into two parts:

First part: There is an interaction Lagrangian for real scalar fields given by
 L=$\lambda_1 \phi_1 \phi_2\phi_3+\lambda_2\phi_1^2\phi_3$.
I need to know how to calculate the decay width of the process $\phi_2 \to \phi_1\phi_1\phi_1$.
I know that there are 2 vertices with corresponding couplings $\lambda_2,\lambda_1 $ and that $\phi_3$ is an internal line. However, I never seen any calculation of amplitude including the decay of one particle to three.. (only similar case of coupled quantum harmonic osciilators but this not quiet the problem).

Second part: Kind of the same problem but now this is decay of the lepton tau particle as:
$\tau \to \nu_{\tau}+ \hat\nu_{e}+e$.
Now the propogator is $W^{-}$ gauge boson, and we have two vertices with corresponding coupling for each - $\frac{g}{\sqrt2}$.
The problem is similar: how to calculate the amplitude?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_decay#Decay_rate

Comment: What is your conceptual problem with three particles in the final state?

Comment: How to calculate the amplitude $|M|^2$?

Comment: Can you draw the Feynman diagram? Have you learned how to write the amplitude for a Feynman diagram?

Comment: Yes, but this type of diagrams I donwt understand from where to where the momentum go in the graph? and does I need to multiply at each vertice coupling as the harmonic osccilator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

For the first part, I think this is what you want to ask. In any case, the couplings should be in the vertices.